# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: git, ubuntu-20.04, git-gui

I'm trying to install this `sudo apt-get install gitk git-gui`

But code gives this error:

```
Err:1 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tcl amd64 8.6.9+1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
Err:2 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tk amd64 8.6.9+1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tcltk-defaults/tcl_8.6.9+1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tcltk-defaults/tk_8.6.9+1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

P.S: I've already tried `update` ,  `upgrade` , `update --fix-missing` commands. But nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `apt`list of repositories seem to be corrupted in file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
The repository `az.archive.ubuntu.com` that you use is not the standard one
for Ubuntu.

To restore the `source.list` file to its initial value, see Ask Ubuntu for
the answers in the post
[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

This command recreates the file after removing it:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then open *Software & Updates* and restore the repositories.

For information about the format of this file, see the article
[Repositories/CommandLine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You literally made my day!. Problem has been SOLVED.:))

Comment: What's wrong with `az.archive.ubuntu.com`? It looks like a standard mirror for Azerbaijan. Ubuntu uses `XY.archive.ubuntu.com` format for mirrors.

Comment: @gronostaj: We can't know what went wrong with that repository, perhaps linked to that country just finishing fighting a war. The standard main repository worked, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a longshot, but I also had this error on KDE Neon about 2 months ago.

It turns out that my gpg files were all fine. I just happened to be on public wi-fi on vacation.

"Network is unreachable" can *potentially* mean that you are being blocked by the az.archive.ubuntu.com servers if they do not recognize your IP as safe. Switching to a VPN fixed the issue for me, as did returning home a few days later.

I am not sure what the issue was in your case, but it's worth documenting that this error can be due to where you are connecting to the ubuntu.com servers from.